# Need to pull path info from file to create new file at same location

Tags: c#, filesystems

I am trying to traverse a directory with thousands of subdirectories.  In each subdirectory there is a .nfo file.

```
D:\Test\
D:\Test\Dir1\
D:\Test\Dir1\file1.nfo
D:\Test\Dir2\
D:\Test\Dir2\file2.nfo
D:\Test\Dir3\
D:\Test\Dir3\file3.nfo
```

I am using Xdocument to parse some info from it, and I need to create a new file in the same location as the source .nfo file.

```
D:\Test\
D:\Test\Dir1\
D:\Test\Dir1\file1.nfo
NEW FILE: D:\Test\Dir1\info.nfo
D:\Test\Dir2\
D:\Test\Dir2\file2.nfo
NEW FILE: D:\Test\Dir2\info.nfo
D:\Test\Dir3\
D:\Test\Dir3\file3.nfo
NEW FILE: D:\Test\Dir3\info.nfo
```

I think I have all of the basic parts, but I can't figure out how to create the new file in the same location as the source file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
string strID = null;
string[] filesNFO = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Test\", "*.nfo", SearchOption.AllDirectories); 

foreach(string file in filesNFO)  
{
     var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
     strID = doc.Root.Element("id") == null ? "" : doc.Root.Element("id").Value;

     FileStream fs = new FileStream("info.nfo", FileMode.Create);
     StreamWriter info = new StreamWriter(fs);
     info.Write("http://powerhostcrm.com/" + strID);
     info.Close();
}
```

Comment: isn't the directory "D:\Test\" ?

Comment: No, there are nfo files in subdirectories of D:\Test\.  I need the info.nfo file created in each of those subdirectories using the infomation parsed from the nfo in those subdirectories.  I added some more detail to my post, hopefully that helps.

Comment: so all the .nfo files live in D:\Test and subdirectories correct?

Comment: Also why are you reading the file with XDocument

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understood the question but have you checked the `FileInfo` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece missing is *where* to save the new file to. If that's the case, take the `file` from the `filesNFO` and grab the directory. I'd also suggesting wrapping everything in using statements:

```
string strID;
string[] filesNFO = Directory.GetFiles( @"D:\Test\", "*.nfo", SearchOption.AllDirectories );

foreach( string file in filesNFO )
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load( file );
    strID = doc.Root.Element( "id" ) == null ? "" : doc.Root.Element( "id" ).Value;

    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName( file );
    string infoNfo = Path.Combine( directory, "info.nfo" );

    using( var fs = new FileStream( infoNfo, FileMode.Create ) )
    using( var info = new StreamWriter( fs ) )
    {
        info.Write( "http://powerhostcrm.com/" + strID );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(string file in filesNFO)  
{
   FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
   string current_dir = info.DirectoryName;
   string newFileBane = current_dir + @"\newfilename.nfo";

   //open filestream
   //write to filestream
}
```

Comment: There is no need to create a `FileInfo` object; you can just use the `Path.GetDirectoryName` method. See my answer.